# Error on running a clean react-native project

Tags: react-native

Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.

> error: bundling failed: Error: invalid value for dynamic deps
>   behavior: `null`

```
at getDynamicDepsBehavior (C:\Projects\react-native\test\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker\index.js:185:13)
at postTransform (C:\Projects\react-native\test\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker\index.js:131:26)
at Object.transformCode [as transform] (C:\Projects\react-native\test\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker\index.js:251:17)
at execMethod (C:\Projects\react-native\test\node_modules\jest-worker\build\child.js:92:29)
at process.on (C:\Projects\react-native\test\node_modules\jest-worker\build\child.js:42:7)
at process.emit (events.js:160:13)
at emit (internal/child_process.js:790:12)
```

BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.

Comment: Seeing the exact same issue here on mac as well.
Trying to run the `react-native bundle` command to no avail

Comment: _Just_ upgraded from RN 0.47 to RN 0.52 and seeing the same error as well.

Comment: I also updated RN from 0.49 to 0.52

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a bad version of metro was published: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/126

Tried a fresh install and things are working now. Just running "npm install metro" to update to the hotfixed version (0.24.6) should also do the trick.

Comment: Seems to have resolved the issue. Removing the `node_modules` and running `npm install` resolved the issue

Comment: For me `0.24.7` resulted in a similar error, but moving back to `0.24.6` fixed it.